# quickSort algorithm on GeeksForGeeks question

Tags: python, quicksort

I have a question about the quickSort algorithm on the GeeksForGeeks website here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-quicksort/

The quickSort consists of the partition function shown on GeeksForGeeks as follows:

```
def partition(arr, low, high):
    i = (low-1)         # index of smaller element
    pivot = arr[high]     # pivot
  
    for j in range(low, high):
  
        # If current element is smaller than or
        # equal to pivot
        if arr[j] <= pivot:
  
            # increment index of smaller element
            i = i+1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
  
    arr[i+1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i+1]
    return (i+1)
```

I am wondering why `i` is set to `i = low - 1`.

Why can't the function be rewritten like this (Notice all the `i`'s):

```
def partition(arr, low, high):
        i = low
        pivot = arr[high]
      
        for j in range(low, high):
      
            if arr[j] <= pivot:
                arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
                i += 1

        arr[i], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i]
        return i
```

Comment: So, did you try on enough random inputs? Any problems?

Comment: What happened when you ran the second version? Did you compare results of both versions? Did you try to analyze what is the meaning of `i`'s value? Did you try to run the code with a debugger and see what happens step by step?

Comment: I did a problem on Leetcode for sorting arrays and the second changed partition function seems to work just as well as the the original on GeeksForGeeks. I think I understand it now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of quicksort works. There are multiple *correct* implementations of quicksort out there. My guess is that GeeksForGeeks chose this implementation, but as to why they chose it?

You'd have to ask the writer of the article.

I think your question brings up a good point, that is, algorithms can be implemented in different, but *similar* ways.

I quickly wrote a script to test your version of the quicksort implementation. See it below.

```
def partition(arr, low, high):
    i = low        # index of smaller element
    pivot = arr[high]     # pivot
  
    for j in range(low, high):
  
        # If current element is smaller than or
        # equal to pivot
        if arr[j] <= pivot:
  
            # increment index of smaller element
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
            i = i+1
  
    arr[i], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i]
    return i
  
  
def quickSort(arr, low, high):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    if low < high:
  
        # pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now
        # at right place
        pi = partition(arr, low, high)
  
        # Separately sort elements before
        # partition and after partition
        quickSort(arr, low, pi-1)
        quickSort(arr, pi+1, high)
  
  
# Driver code to test above
arr = []
for i in range(0, 10000):
    import random
    r = random.randint(-100000,100000)
    arr.append(r)
n = len(arr)
quickSort(arr, 0, n-1)
# using naive method to 
# check sorted list 
flag = 0
i = 1
while i < len(arr):
    if(arr[i] < arr[i - 1]):
        flag = 1
    i += 1
      
# printing result
if (not flag) :
    print ("Sorted")
else :
    print ("Not sorted")
    print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its all about efficiency, by starting `i` at `low` and starting `j` at `low`, you are testing a value against itself in the first run of the loop, which does absolutely nothing in the scope of sorting an array.

To change that and keep the efficiency, you would have to change the implementation of the quickSort method (as in the one that calls `partition`) but by doing that you end up touching the same index multiple times between the two recursive calls, which decreases efficiency again.

Quicksort is all about speed (hence the name). The changes you made, definitely don't break the algorithm, however when you scale up the input it does decrease it's speed.

Comment: Yes, but your point about the difference in time is a moot point. The time complexity of their implementation is still O(nlogn)